# can i display only first column of somefield in kibana visualiz

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have one filed called result it have data like below

```
result: mysite.com location: 4834 order_item: 227541
```

I want to display only site_name i.e mysite.com in kibana visualiz.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways come to mind:

- parse the item out before you insert it into elasticsearch (e.g. logstash)
- use [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting) (disabled by default) to parse the message.